# jQuery - Have 3 Randomly Chosen Values From An Array Each Equal a Varible

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, var

Lets say I have this:

```
fooArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]; 
var val1;
var val2;
var val3;
```

How can I randomly choose 3 values from `fooArray` and then have each variable equal one of those 3 values?

Each variable must equal a different value, but that value has to be randomly chosen.

Comment: I would shuffle the array and then pop it three times to get my three values

Comment: Do you care about data inside the array?

Comment: @derp the only thing is that the three values have to be different

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes, what I have up there is just an example

Comment: This question is already closed! No answer can be posted! Better check the link above.